# Django: What are the downsides of manually altering model fields with SQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

Since `syncdb` doesn't alter existing tables [[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)] I'm wondering what the downsides would be of logging in to a database and altering the structure.

More specifically I'd want to know what potential problems could be triggered if I change the length or type of a field (e.g. `INT` to `BIGINT`).

Will there be any issues with Django trying to truncate or alter the value to fit within the scope defined in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downsides ? If you are talking about simple project, then there arent any. Do whatever pleases  you :). If the project grows bigger, then read next paragraph :P

If it is larger project and has other contributors (and even if it does not), you need to version control it. And for this reason, manual changes are BAD. Cause you just cant go back to earlier version without changing the database.... BUT....

But since you are talking about doing this manually, i feel, that i need to point out the existance of http://south.aeracode.org/

Which is created exactly for the reason that you, perhaps, should not be doing this manually.

BTW. im trolling here and talking tongue in cheek... don't take this post 100% seriously :P

Comment: While I get that you were being light-hearted in your response, someone not familiar with the subject might find it difficult to work out which bits were advice and which were jokes, so I hope you don't mind that I wrote out a slightly more concrete answer :)

Comment: Good job, old chap. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

[Django South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the solution to this problem. It is a "must have" app to include (and here I'm going to disagree with @OdifYitsaeb's answer) in ANY project, not just large ones. It is so simple and powerful that you are essentially creating more work for yourself if you don't use it even in a tiny personal project.

It's soon to be included into Django core in (I beleive) 1.7 as well, so it's a good idea to get familiar with it now.

Comment: how about `django-evolution` ??

Comment: Put it this way, django-evolution is not the worst schema migration system I've seen in place for legacy django apps. Thank god for South.

Comment: Without south, things might go.. well.. south..